# Запрос для подсчета количества двух заданных значений в связанной таблице

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
    tb_sites:
    ---------
    id,
    category_id,
    name,
    url
```

и

```
    tb_comments:
    -----------
    id,
    id_site,
    type
```

`type` - может быть 0 (отрицательный) и 1 (положительный)

Нужно получить количество положительных и отрицательных отзывов для каждого сайта. Попробовал решить задачу так:

```
    SELECT COUNT(negative.id) AS negative_comments, COUNT(positive.id) as positive_comments, s.category_id, s.id, s.name, s.url
    FROM tb_sites AS s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_comment AS negative ON s.id = negative.id_site AND negative.type = 0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_comment AS positive ON s.id = positive.id_site AND positive.type = 1
    GROUP BY s.url
    ORDER BY positive_comments DESC LIMIT 5
```

Считает правильно и неправильно одновременно. Когда комментарии есть только положительные или отрицательные - всё считает правильно, но если есть и те и те виды комментариев, то начинаются сбои - отображается число больше, чем есть на самом деле.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
SELECT
    sum(case when comment.type=0 then 1 else 0 end) as negative,
    sum(case when comment.type=1 then 1 else 0 end) as positive,
    s.category_id, s.id, s.name, s.url
FROM tb_sites AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_comment AS comment ON s.id = comment.id_site
GROUP BY s.category_id, s.id, s.name, s.url
ORDER BY positive DESC;
```

`sum(case when comment.type=0 then 1 else 0 end)` - посчитает количество (или сумму единиц для) тех строк, где `comment.type = 0`

Comment: А можете рассказать немного о магии которая заключены в

    case when comment.type=1 then 1 else 0 end

Comment: @Angus123, добавил "миниописание" в ответ